# How to export dynamodb table using boto3?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have written below the AWS lambda function to export dynamodb table to the S3 bucket. But when I execute the below code, I am getting an error

> 'dynamodb.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'export_table_to_point_in_time'

```
import boto3
import datetime



def lambda_handler(event,context):
    client = boto3.resource('dynamodb',endpoint_url="http://localhost:8000")
    response = client.export_table_to_point_in_time(
        TableArn='table arn string',
        ExportTime=datetime(2015, 1, 1),
        S3Bucket='my-bucket',
        S3BucketOwner='string',
        ExportFormat='DYNAMODB_JSON'
    )

    print("Response :", response)
```

Boto 3 version : 1.24.82

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ExportTableToPointInTime` is not available on DynamoDB Local, so if you are trying to do it in local (assumed from the localhost endpoint) you cannot.

Moreover, the [`Resource`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#service-resource) client does not have that API. You must use the [`Client`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#client) client.

```
import boto3
dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')
```